# Computing $f(5)$

Tags: functions

> f is linear and one-to-one function such that
>
> $$(f+f)(x) = (f \circ f)(x)$$
> Compute $f(5)$.

We're told that f is linear, which implies

$$f(x) = ax+b$$

Then plugging this into the given equation

$$\biggr [2(2ax+b)\biggr ] (x) = f(ax+b)$$

Let $ax+b = 5$

$$(10)(x) = f(5)$$

Here I think I got the correct answer, 10. However, are my steps mathematically correct?

Regards

Comment: You have a typo there in the middle: it should be $\;\left[2(ax+b)\right]\;$ ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand very well what you have done.

Here's my try:

$$(f+f)(x)=2ax+2b$$
$$f\circ f(x)=a(ax+b)+b=a^2x+ab+b$$

Since $f+f=f\circ f$,
$$\left\{\begin{align}a^2&=2a\\2b&=ab+b\end{align}\right.$$

This system has two solutions: $a=b=0$ and $a=2$, $b=0$. In the first case, $f$ would not be injective, and in the other $f(5)=10$.

Comment: But, in the first case, $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed that condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you haven't, but you've come close.

By definition, $$(f+f)(x)=f(x)+f(x),$$ so since $f$ is linear, then $$(f+f)(x)=ax+b+ax+b=2ax+2b.$$

You've used the definition of $(f\circ f)(x)$ correctly, but didn't follow through. $$f(ax+b)=a(ax+b)+b=a^2x+ab+b.$$ So, we know that $$2ax+2b=a^2x+ab+b.$$ Can you take it from there to figure out what $a$ and $b$ are? Once you do that, finding $f(5)$ should be straightforward.